# Call FactSet refresh from VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the Excel add-in of the FactSet app and loads of FDS formulas across sheets.

I want to be able to refresh FactSet formulas for individual sheets or selections. How do I call this from the standard VBA code?

What I have now is a line of code that calls FactSet refresh for entire workbook:

```
ExecuteExcel4Macro "FDSFORCERECALC(FALSE)"
```

Answer (score 0):

To recalculate the =FDS codes in the selected cells:

ExecuteExcel4Macro ("FDSFORCERECALC(TRUE)")